# почему return не возвращает значение константы?

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю почему return не возвращает значение локальной newItem наружу в addToList().

```
function createElements(value) {
  const newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.textContent = `${value}`;
  const trashIcon = document.createElement('div');
  trashIcon.classList.add('delete');
  return newItem;
}


function addToList(value) {
  
  list.prepend(newItemCopy);
  newItem.append(trashIcon);
  console.log(todoDB);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы функция `createElements` что-то куда-то возвращала, ее надо, по крайней мере, *вызвать*.

```
function createElements(value) {
  const newItem = document.createElement('li');
  newItem.textContent = `${value}`;
  const trashIcon = document.createElement('div');
  trashIcon.classList.add('delete');
  newItem.append(trashIcon);
  return newItem;
}

function addToList(value) {
  ...
  const newItem = createElements(value);
  ...
}
```

P.S. Переменные, объявленные внутри функции, не видны снаружи.